Tkinter canvas object tag_bind causing memory leak
If I monitor the Windows task manager while a program of mine is running, I see a memory usage number that goes up continuously. I wrote the attached code to demonstrate the problem. Once a tag_bind has been added to a canvas, no matter how I try to unbind the canvas objects, the memory usage never goes down, and successive bindings ask for more and more.
I've run the binding statements thousands of times to magnify the effect.
my code :
from tkinter import *

import os, psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
def showmem(): print(f'{process.memory_info().rss:,}')

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)

def bind_one(canvas, r) :
    canvas.tag_unbind(r, "<ButtonPress-1>") #This has no effect on memory
    
    def procedure(r, event) : print(r,event)    
    canvas.tag_bind(r, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event : procedure(r,event))

def unbind_all(R, canvas) :
    for r in R : canvas.tag_unbind(r, "<ButtonPress-1>")
    showmem()
Button(root, text = 'unbind', command = lambda : unbind_all(R, canvas)).grid()

def rebind_all(R, canvas) :
    def procedure(r, event) : print(r,event)
    for r in R : canvas.tag_bind(r, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event, r = r : procedure(r, event))
    showmem()
Button(root, text = 'rebind', command = lambda : rebind_all(R, canvas)).grid()

R = []
s = 50
for j in range(6) :
    for k in range(6) :
      R += [canvas.create_rectangle(k*s,j*s,(k+1)*s,(j+1)*s, fill = 'white')]

x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox('all')
canvas.config(width=x2, height=y2)
    
showmem()

count = 0
for k in range(2000) :
    for r in R : bind_one(canvas, r)  #line A
    if count == 100 :
        showmem()
        count = 0
    count += 1

showmem()               
   
canvas.grid()

mainloop()


The memory leak is caused from the tkinter canvas updating very fast. Sadly, there is no direct fix to this problem, although you can do some things to make the leak smaller.
Possible fixes:
You can use a different GUI module like PyQT5 that has less memory leaks or you can lessen the burden on the updating by removing some event checks.
That's all that I can offer. There's no cure to inefficiency without using arbitrary methods. :) I hope this helped!

Also, (because I don't have fifty reputation to comment on your post), unbinding actually helps with the memory because it disables the checks on your wanted event.

Thanks. I tried deleting the objects from the canvas, recreating and rebinding; it did not help. I tried destroying the entire canvas and starting with a new instance; this helped but had other problems, and memory usage still accumulated. So, instead of doing a lot of unbinding and rebinding, I guess I'm going to try leaving the objects bound and making an 'enabled' boolean accessible to the bound method that tells it whether or not to do anything.
